# How to get the emails of the owners of Outlook's shared calendars

Tags: c#, outlook, interop

I'm using the Interop API to get appointments from Outlook's shared calendars. I can only do this if I know in advance the email of the owner of the shared calendars.

I would like to be able to get the owner's email of each shared calendar before looping appointment's item in the shared calendars. Every contribution is well appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean you want the calendar folders that are already cached by Outlook in the current session? Or that you want to open calendars of every person in your Exchange org?

Answer (score 1):

To get a shared calendar folder you need to use the [GetSharedDefaultFolder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869575(v=office.15).aspx) method of the `Namespace` class which returns a `Folder` object that represents the specified default folder for the specified user. This method is used in a delegation scenario, where one user has delegated access to another user for one or more of their default folders (for example, their shared Calendar folder). For example:

```
Sub ResolveName()  
 Dim myNamespace As Outlook.NameSpace  
 Dim myRecipient As Outlook.Recipient  
 Dim CalendarFolder As Outlook.Folder 
 Set myNamespace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")  
 Set myRecipient = myNamespace.CreateRecipient("Eugene Astafiev")  
 myRecipient.Resolve  
 If myRecipient.Resolved Then  
 Call ShowCalendar(myNamespace, myRecipient)  
 End If  
End Sub 

Sub ShowCalendar(myNamespace, myRecipient)  
 Dim CalendarFolder As Outlook.Folder 
 Set CalendarFolder = _  
 myNamespace.GetSharedDefaultFolder _  
 (myRecipient, olFolderCalendar)  
 CalendarFolder.Display  
End Sub
```

The Outlook object model doesn't provide anything for getting a list of shared folders. The best what you can do is to iterate over your address book entries and try to reach shared folders.